# Is there an external, up-to-date tool that can render scenes made in Carrara?

Tags: 3d, graphic-design

[Carrara](https://www.daz3d.com/carrara-8-5) is a 3D modelling tool that has the advantage of being easy to use for my purposes (creating landscapes), but the disadvantage is it has not been updated since 2013, and its unlikely, I would guess, that future updates will occur.

I'd like to continue using Carrara for creating scenes, but the rendering tool is probably 10 years out-of-date. Is there any software tool that can completely render a scene created in Carrara, but that is up-to-date, so takes advantages of newer ways to render?

Comment: Thanks for the conformation. Is it possible to export into different formats? What OS are you using and what price might be ok for you?

Comment: Windows. It can export to 3DS, 3DMF, CAE, COLLADA, DXF, Direct X, FBX, Shockwave 3D, VRML, Wavefront OBJ, VET. Budget of $100.